# dart pub version conflicts

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am trying to learn angulardart. I followed [starter guide](https://angulardart.dev/guide/setup) and using IDE intellij.

After I have cloned the repo and then opened index.html in browser directly from intellij I am getting this error

```
/usr/local/opt/dart/libexec/bin/pub global run webdev serve web:53322
webdev could not run for this project.
The `build_runner` version – 1.2.3 – is not within the allowed constraint – >=1.3.0 <2.0.0.
The `build_web_compilers` version – 0.4.4+3 – is not within the allowed constraint – >=1.2.0 <3.0.0.
Dart Webdev terminated
```

I have not done any change in any file and everything is as present in the repo. Can someone please help me to understand what is missing or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that I asked a noob question. So I went and updated pubspec.yml file and changed dependencies version for build_runner and build_web_compilers to what is shown in error.

This has solved my problem. Leaving the question here in case someone face the same issue in future.

**EDITED**

Sharing the updated pubspec.yml file here

```
name: angular_app
description: A web app that uses AngularDart
version: 0.0.1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.0.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular: ^5.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: ^2.0.0
  build_runner: '>=1.3.0 <2.0.0'
  build_test: ^0.10.2
  build_web_compilers: ' >=1.2.0 <3.0.0'
  test: ^1.0.0
```

Comment: @ValeryKulikov I updated my answer with the updated pubspec.yml file. Please see and ask if anything else is needed. I hope this helps.